# RMAN backup data of specific DB only

Tags: oracle, rman

For an ORACLE_SID (service?) there is a backup using RMAN configured and scheduled.
At the SID are multiple DBs but only one of those needs backup of the data. For the rest backup of the definitions and settings is enough. Is such an RMAN configuration possible?

Comment: By "multiple DBs", do you mean pluggable databases, or something else?

Comment: Yes, it is about PDBs. Did not know about PDB before your question, so thanks for that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... only one of those needs backup of the data. For the rest backup of the definitions and settings is enough. Is such an RMAN configuration possible?

Short answer: No.

An RMAN Backup includes *everything* needed to **Recover** that database.
Because "Pluggable Databases" are more akin to "Tablespaces on Steroids", the only *actual* Database you have here is the *Container* Database.  Backup the Container and you get everything inside it.
There's no way round that.

Of course, you could use *other* tools, like Data Dump (expdp & impdp) to extract files that contain just the structure of some of the Pluggable Databases and "restore" those independently.

Comment: The [manual](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMQS/GUID-86822B10-B187-4E41-9A8F-93BFFBD143E9.htm) seems to suggest otherwise: "You can perform backup and recovery operations on a single pluggable database (PDB) or on multiple PDBs."

Comment: Looking at the restrictions on backing up Pluggable Databases, I would suggest that they're not really suitable to support a complete, point-in-time Recovery strategy.  YMMV.